# Differences of Squares on $1-2\sin^2(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm working through Khan Academy's Calculus courses and I came across a step in a problem that simplified the following using differences of squares.

I can't figure out how the difference of squares was found as it doesn't appear to match any other examples of difference of squares that I found online.

[image]

For clarity the transformation performed is:

\begin{equation}
1-2\sin^2 {\theta} = \left(1+\sqrt{2}\sin{\theta}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{2}\sin{\theta}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: you mean that $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ ? Thats just that with sin function and $\sqrt 2$ .....

Comment: Put $a=1$ and $b=\sqrt{2}\sin\theta$ in the above identity.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch someone has edited the post we cant see it yet

Comment: @Isham Thanks for informing me.  I was hoping the entire equation would be put in the question so I've edited it in myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All "Difference of Squares" really is is the use of the equation $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$. In the case shown, $a=1$ and $b=\sqrt2\sin\theta$.